# Can I install arm64 libraries on x86_64 with homebrew?

Tags: homebrew

I am cross-compiling on x86_64 MacOS 11 for arm64 architecture.
clang/XCode support it but I face an issue when external library is required.
Let it be boost, for example.  I know that the bottle for arm64 is available but it looks like there is no way to select it for installation.

`arch -arm64 brew ...`    says that this architecture is unknown which sounds fair.

So the question is wheather there is an option to force brew install bottles for 'foreign' architecture ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to Homebrew team
https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/2843

I made it work with the code like this:

```
setopt sh_word_split
mkdir arm-homebrew && curl -L https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C arm-homebrew 
alias arm-brew='$(pwd)/arm-homebrew/bin/brew'
response=$(arm-brew fetch --force --bottle-tag=arm64_big_sur boost | grep "Downloaded to")
parsed=($response)  
arm-brew install $parsed[3]
```

Comment: Why the second homebrew install?

Comment: @Adam
We are installing arm64 libraries on x86_64 host
The first homebrew is 'native' x86_64
The second homebrew is 'foreign' arm64

Comment: How does the "foreign" one know it's foreign?

Comment: I ask because when I try the same with just the regular native `brew`, it works fine. The important part is the `--bottle-tag=arm64_big_sur` switch.

Comment: @Adam
Imagine you are creating fat(universal) binary that depends on some library. Let it it be boost.  In this case you will need both arm64 and x86_64 versions  and single instance of homebrew cannot have both installed.

There may be other practical scenarios when you need to have support for both architectures simultaniously, for example, code generation with thirift or protobuf.

Answer (score 0):

Native system `brew` can be asked to download any desired bottle version with two switches:

- `--force` ignores the compatibility check
- `--bottle-tag=arm64_big_sur` downloads the ARM Big Sur build. This assumes the formula has this build, check the formula `.rb` for available tags. Big Sur is the earliest macOS with ARM support.

Then use `brew --cache` to get the filename of the downloaded bottle and pass to `brew install`:

```bash
brew fetch --force --bottle-tag=arm64_big_sur boost
brew install $(brew --cache --bottle-tag=arm64_big_sur boost)
```

You can verify that it worked with `cd $(brew --prefix boost)` then use `file` on any `.dylib` files to see what architecture they're built for.

If the formula has any dependencies then they will still be installed normally (for the native architecture), so you may have to follow the same process for them.

Comment: This is correct theoretically but is useless practically IMHO.  I believe that for the libraries like boost you will need both  native and foreign versions.