# How to solve libmagic.dylib - incompatible architecture error?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to install my Django project to my M1 Mac laptop but it is giving errors.

```
..OSError: dlopen(/Users/e.celik/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/magic/libmagic/libmagic.dylib, 0x0006): tried: 
'/Users/e.celik/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/magic/libmagic/libmagic.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), 
'/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/e.celik/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/magic/libmagic/libmagic.dylib' (no such file), 
'/Users/e.celik/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/magic/libmagic/libmagic.dylib' 
(mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))
```

I do not know why is this happening?
I'm using python 3.8 and last version of pip.

How can I fix that?

Comment: How did you install *Python* on the machine?

Comment: @CristiFati with brew install python

Comment: `arch -arm64 brew install python`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70822921/4788546.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem and I could fix it by doing the next steps:

1. Uninstall libmagic with `brew uninstall libmagic`
2. Install it again with `arch -arm64 brew install libmagic`
3. Copy the file `libmagic.dylib` from `/usr/local/Cellar/libmagic/lib` into `site-packages/magic/libmagic/` of the project.